# Text on a ProgressBar in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, controls, progress-bar

This may be a no-brainer for the WPF cognoscenti, but I'd like to know if there's a simple way to put text on the WPF ProgressBar. To me, an empty progress bar looks naked. That's screen real estate that could carry a message about **what** is in progress, or even just add numbers to the representation. Now, WPF is all about containers and extensions and I'm slowly wrapping my mind around that, but since I don't see a "Text" or "Content" property, I'm thinking I'm going to have to add something to the container that is my progress bar. Is there a technique or two out there that is more natural than my original WinForms impulses will be? What's the best, most WPF-natural way to add text to that progress bar?

Comment: You can go for this - [WPF Progress Bar with dynamic text and text color update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167867/wpf-progress-bar-with-dynamic-text-text-color-update)

Comment: ++ for using the word cognoscenti

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are needing to have a reusable method for adding text, you can create a new Style/ControlTemplate that has an additional TextBlock to display the text.  You can hijack the TextSearch.Text attached property to set the text on a progress bar.

If it doesn't need to be reusable, simply put the progress bar in a Grid and add a TextBlock to the grid.  Since WPF can compose elements together, this will work nicely.

If you want, you can create a UserControl that exposes the ProgressBar and TextBlock as public properties, so it would be less work than creating a custom ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 71):

Both of the prior responses (creating a new `CustomControl` or an `Adorner`) are better practices, but if you just want quick and dirty (or to understand visually how to do it) then this code would work:

```
<Grid Width="300" Height="50">  
   <ProgressBar Value="50" />
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
      My Text
   </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Just keep in mind that the z-index is such that the last item listed will be on top.

Also, if you don't have [Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/) yet, be sure to pick it up - it is great for playing with XAML when you're trying to figure things out.

Comment: This is the route I went down originally however it should be noted that on systems which with the UI set to Windows Classic or on XP the progress bar will show with dark blue which will make the text unreadable.

Answer (score 39):

**This can be very simple** (unless there are alot of ways getting this to work).

You could use `Style` to get this done or you just overlay a `TextBlock` and a `ProgressBar`.

I personally use this to show the percentage of the progress when waiting for completion.

> To keep it very simple I only wanted to have **one** `Binding` only,
>   so I attached the `TextBock.Text` to the `ProgressBar.Value`.

**Then just copy the Code to get it done.**

```
<Grid>
   <ProgressBar Minimum="0" 
                Maximum="100" 
                Value="{Binding InsertBindingHere}" 
                Name="pbStatus" />
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=pbStatus, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

**Here is how this could look like:**

[image]

Check out [WPF Tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/) for the full post.

Answer (score 6):

You could use an Adorner to display text over top of it.

See [MSDN article on Adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(VS.85).aspx#adorn_single_element)

You would create a class that inherits from the Adorner class.  Override the OnRender method to draw the text that you want.  If you want you could create a dependency property for your custom Adorner that contains the text that you want to display.  Then use the example in the link I mentioned to add this Adorner to your progress bar's adorner layer.

Answer (score 5):

ProgressBar with Text and Binding from 2 Properties ( **Value/Maximum value** ):

```
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar Name="pbUsrLvl"
                 Minimum="1" 
                 Maximum="99" 
                 Value="59" 
                 Margin="5"  
                 Height="24"  Foreground="#FF62FF7F"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}UserLvl:{0}/{1}">
                <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="pbUsrLvl" />
                <Binding Path="Maximum" ElementName="pbUsrLvl" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Rezult:

[image]

---

The same but **with % of progress** :

```
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar Name="pbLifePassed"
                 Minimum="0" 
                 Value="59" 
                 Maximum="100"
                 Margin="5" Height="24" Foreground="#FF62FF7F"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=pbLifePassed, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click `ProgressBar`, and click Edit Template > Edit a Copy.

Then put the `TextBlock` as shown below just above the closing tag of `Grid` in the Style generated by VS.

```
   <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2"/>
   <TextBlock Background="Transparent" Text="work in progress" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Center"/>
 </Grid>
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the given answers.
Since I´m using MahApps Metro, I ended up with this:

```
<Grid>
    <metro:MetroProgressBar x:Name="pbar" Value="50" Height="20"></metro:MetroProgressBar>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=pbar, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

If you want to use the normal bar with Metro Style:

```
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="pbar" Value="50" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource MetroProgressBar}"></ProgressBar>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=pbar, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Same without Style:

```
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="pbar" Value="60" Height="20" Style="{x:Null}"></ProgressBar>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=pbar, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

What is Happening?

You have your progressbar and simply just lay text over it.
So you just use your progressbar as you would.
Put the progressbar in a grid and lay an textblock in it.
Then you can text as you wish or grab the current percenteage wich is the value from the progressbar.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is to write anything you want in a textBlock after the progress bar, and change its left margin to a negativ number.

```
<ProgressBar  BorderBrush="black" Width="250" Height="20" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Happiness}"/>

            <TextBlock Margin="-140,0" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Happiness}" ></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Margin="-135,0" FontSize="20"  >%</TextBlock>
```