# Progress bar with dynamic text & text color update

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I've a progressbar whose text changes dynamically. I want to update the appearance of it such that as soon as progress comes over text then text color should update. Something like this. [image]

I need text color of text (black) appearing above blue background should automatically change to white. However text having white background should remain black.

Comment: honestly, i dont find your idea really beautiful. but 1 idea: write the same text in white over your progressbar and crop the overlaying part..l.

Comment: I have attached snapshot of only progress bar from my app. I cant change the progress bar behavior as you suggested.. When you see this over complete app then this seems to work good apart from text color not changeable..

Comment: Though i've added White Shadow effect which seems to work good but i'm looking for a nice solution. such that text color changes with progress bar completion.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using a modified version of the `ProgressBars` default `Template`. It contains two `TextBlocks`

- The first `TextBlock` is the black one
- The second `TextBlock` is the white one. This `TextBlock` has the Width of the full control and `Clip` set to the Width of the progress part

[image]

The text of the `ProgressBar` is binding to the `Tag` property. Usable like this.

```
<ProgressBar TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold"
             Tag="ProgressBar Text"
             Foreground="Blue"
             Style="{DynamicResource MyProgressBarStyle}"/>
```

**MyProgressBarStyle**

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarBackground" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#BABABA" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#C7C7C7" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#BABABA" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarBorderBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#B2B2B2" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#8C8C8C" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarGlassyHighlight" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#50FFFFFF" Offset="0.5385"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.5385"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarTopHighlight" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#80FFFFFF" Offset="0.05"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.25"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFFF" Offset="0.4"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFFF" Offset="0.6"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorDarkEdgeLeft" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#0C000000" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#20000000" Offset="0.3"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorDarkEdgeRight" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#20000000" Offset="0.7"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#0C000000" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<RadialGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorLightingEffectLeft" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" RelativeTransform="1,0,0,1,0.5,0.5">
    <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFC4" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFC4" Offset="1"/>
</RadialGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorLightingEffect" EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFC4" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFC4" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<RadialGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorLightingEffectRight" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" RelativeTransform="1,0,0,1,-0.5,0.5">
    <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFC4" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFC4" Offset="1"/>
</RadialGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorGlassyHighlight" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#90FFFFFF" Offset="0.5385"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.5385"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<Style x:Key="MyProgressBarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#01D328"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Grid.ZIndex="2" Foreground="Black"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
                                Grid.ZIndex="3" Foreground="White"
                                Width="{Binding ElementName=rectangle, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                TextAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock.Clip>
                            <RectangleGeometry>
                                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RectConverter}">
                                        <Binding ElementName="Indicator" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                        <Binding ElementName="Indicator" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                            </RectangleGeometry>
                        </TextBlock.Clip>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2"/>
                    <Border Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarGlassyHighlight}" CornerRadius="2" Margin="1"/>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#80FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarTopHighlight}" Margin="1"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track" Margin="1"/>
                    <Decorator x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1">
                        <Grid x:Name="Foreground">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Indicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            <Grid x:Name="Animation" ClipToBounds="true">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_GlowRect" Fill="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-100,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid x:Name="Overlay">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="15"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="15"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="LeftDark" Fill="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndicatorDarkEdgeLeft}" Margin="1,1,0,1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="RightDark" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndicatorDarkEdgeRight}" Margin="0,1,1,1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="LeftLight" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndicatorLightingEffectLeft}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="CenterLight" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndicatorLightingEffect}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="RightLight" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndicatorLightingEffectRight}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                <Border x:Name="Highlight1" Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndicatorGlassyHighlight}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                <Border x:Name="Highlight2" Background="{StaticResource ProgressBarTopHighlight}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Decorator>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="TemplateRoot">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="LeftDark" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="RightDark" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="LeftLight" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="CenterLight" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="RightLight" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Indicator" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Animation" Value="#80B5FFA9"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**RectConverter**

```
public class RectConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double width = (double)values[0];
        double height = (double)values[1];
        return new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice XAML-only solution (value converter notwithstanding, obviously)! :)

Comment: Eh, I just tend to consider value converters the cost of doing WPF-business. At least they pretty-neatly encapsulate specific bits of logic, if you write / organize them well...

Comment: @djacobson: Of course, value converters are a big part of WPF. But I like them better when they're actually converting something and not just double for double. But since the Geometry classes are using structs all over the place the Rect converter is required

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution in Silverlight but it should be easy to convert it to WPF.

I'm using linear gradient brush to change the text color in the text block, I created a user control with a progress bar and a text block, let's call it "SpecialProgressBar"

Here's the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestSilverlightApplication.SpecialProgressBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400"
             x:Name="specialProgressBar">

    <Canvas  Width="Auto"
             Height="Auto">

        <ProgressBar Name="progressBar"
                     IsIndeterminate="False"
                     Background="White"
                     Foreground="Blue"
                     Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=specialProgressBar}"
                     Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=specialProgressBar}" />

        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Text="xxx of yyy" />
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

And here's the code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TestSilverlightApplication
{
    public partial class SpecialProgressBar : UserControl
    {
        private Point _textBlockPosition;
        private readonly LinearGradientBrush _linearGradientBrush;
        private readonly GradientStop _gradientStop;

        public SpecialProgressBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // will be changing this gradient stop as the progress bar value changes
            _gradientStop = new GradientStop
            {
                Color = Colors.Black,
                Offset = 0
            };

            // the default brush we want to start with,
            // you might want to play with the start point x value to get the effect you want
            _linearGradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush
            {
                StartPoint = new Point(-0.2, 0.5),
                EndPoint = new Point(1, 0.5),
                GradientStops = new GradientStopCollection
                {
                    _gradientStop,
                    new GradientStop
                    {
                        Color = Colors.Black,
                        Offset = 1
                    }
                }
            };

            // set the brush to the text block 
            textBlock.Foreground = _linearGradientBrush;

            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(SpecialProgressBar_Loaded);
            progressBar.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(progressBar_ValueChanged);
        }

        private void SpecialProgressBar_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // center text block on top of the progress bar
            _textBlockPosition = new Point(progressBar.Width / 2 - textBlock.ActualWidth / 2,
                                           progressBar.Height / 2 - textBlock.ActualHeight / 2);

            textBlock.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, _textBlockPosition.X);
            textBlock.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, _textBlockPosition.Y);
        }

        private void progressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            // print out the value in the text block
            textBlock.Text = string.Concat(e.NewValue, " of ", progressBar.Maximum);

            // get the value relative to the size of the progress bar
            var x = e.NewValue / progressBar.Maximum * progressBar.Width;             

            // if the value is equal to or greater than the position of the text block on the canvas (on the progress bar)
            // then we want to change the gradient offset and color.
            if (x >= _textBlockPosition.X)
            {
                _gradientStop.Offset += 0.1 * textBlock.ActualWidth / progressBar.Width;
                _gradientStop.Color = Colors.White;

                // when we pass the end of the text block we don't need the gradient any more,
                // replace it with a solid white color
                if (_gradientStop.Offset >= 1)
                {
                    textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The last step is to add the user control to a page (or another user control)

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestSilverlightApplication.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:TestSilverlightApplication="clr-namespace:TestSilverlightApplication"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <TestSilverlightApplication:SpecialProgressBar x:Name="specialProgressBar"
                                                       Width="200"
                                                       Height="40" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And to test it out I added a timer to change the progress bar value:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace TestSilverlightApplication
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Tick += (s, args) => specialProgressBar.progressBar.Value += 1;
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(1000000);
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

This is a quick and dirty solution but it's a start, I think. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Though I dint used the whole solution provided by Meleak, but here is how i did it.

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="SummaryProgressBar"
                         BorderBrush="Black"
                         BorderThickness="1"
                         Background="LightGray"
                         FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                         Maximum="1"
                         MinWidth="200"
                         Width="Auto">
                <ProgressBar.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ArithmeticConverter}"
                                  Mode="OneWay">
                        <Binding Path="ABCCollectionView.Count"/>
                        <Binding Source="{StaticResource DivideArithmeticSymbol}" />
                        <Binding Path="XYZCollectionView.Count"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </ProgressBar.Value>
            </ProgressBar>
            <!-- Black Progress Bar Text -->
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockBlack"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       TextAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       Text="{Binding SummaryText}"
                       Width="{Binding ElementName=SummaryProgressBar, Path=ActualWidth}"></TextBlock>

            <!-- White Progress Bar Text -->
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockWhite"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       TextAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Foreground="White"
                       Text="{Binding SummaryText}"
                       Width="{Binding ElementName=SummaryProgressBar, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <TextBlock.Clip>
                    <RectangleGeometry>
                        <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ProgressBarFillToRectConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="SummaryProgressBar" Path="Value"/>
                                    <Binding ElementName="TextBlockWhite" Path="ActualWidth" />
                                    <Binding ElementName="TextBlockWhite" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                        </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                    </RectangleGeometry>
                </TextBlock.Clip>
            </TextBlock>
```

and here is converter

```
 /// <summary>
/// Converts the ProgressBar Fill percentage width to a Rectangle whose width is calculated by multiplying Fill Percentage to Actual Width of control. Height is passed too.
/// Note: This converter is used in showing WHITE & BLACK text on progress bar. Also use White textblock next to Black not reverse in XAML.
/// </summary>
public class ProgressBarFillToRectConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null && values[0] != null && values[1] != null && values[2] != null)
        {
            double progressBarFillPercentage = (double)values[0];
            double textBlockActualyWidth = (double)values[1];
            double textBlockHeight = (double)values[2];
            return new Rect(0, 0, progressBarFillPercentage * textBlockActualyWidth, textBlockHeight); // ProgressBarFillWidth is calculated by multiplying Fill 
            // percentage with actual width
        }
        return new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0); // Default Zero size rectangle

    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here whole concept is I'm using 2 textboxes for showing same text: One with white foreground and another with black foreground. Both textboxes and progress bar have same width.
Now i clip the textbox with white foreground to a width equal to progress bar fill width so that white textblock is visible only in the portion where progress bar fill appears & the rest of text is of black color.

Comment: I found this question and makred this answer as the one for me. I didn't need to rebuild the progress bar via a control template because, at this time, there's only place in the application for it. I wanted something simple and concise and this was it for me. If we need to use it in more than one place, then I'll most likely throw it in a DataTemplate.