# Partial Text color update

Tags: wpf, textblock

Here is what i've

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock> abc </TextBlock>
    <Textblock> def </Textblock>
    <Textblock> ghi </Textblock>
</Stackpanel>
```

Now on GUI i show all three textblock's text in single line like : abcdefghi . I want to update the partial text color (irrespective of which textblock the textbelong.
Say i want to change the color of 40% of total text to red and other as white. (also the percentage amount is too variable) It will update by Binding. So no hardcoding for text % and any specific textblock.

Done by -.[How to make text color appear differently using 2 textblock for a single text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167867/wpf-progress-bar-with-dynamic-text-text-color-update)

Comment: why r u using 3 textblocks and not one richTextBox ?

Comment: you can  see the reason in link i've added

Comment: You can use a `MultiBinding` to achieve a "x of y" display without using multiple `TextBlock`s. That, plus my technique below will achieve the effect you want, I think.

Comment: Actually i've already did this thing but your blog was quite helpful so marking that as answer :) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with one `TextBlock`, a `LinearGradient` and a few attached properties, as long as you don't mind letters being partially colored.

**EDIT:** I decided to write a post showing the solution with attached properties, but in the meanwhile you could use simple XAML and bindings like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock FontSize="34" FontWeight="Bold"
               Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider, StringFormat={}{0:p0} of this text is coloured}">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1 0">
                <GradientStop Color="BurlyWood" />
                <GradientStop Color="BurlyWood" Offset="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" />
                <GradientStop Color="Beige" Offset="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" />
                <GradientStop Color="Beige" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
    </TextBlock>

    <Slider x:Name="slider" Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Value="0.4" />
</Grid>
```

And if you're interested by the solution using attached properties, you can visit [Partially Coloured TextBlock](http://blog.madd0.com/2011/03/03/Partially-colored-TextBlock/) on my blog.