# WPF - Slider with a range of number - draw bar

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm working on a WPF project with the MVVM pattern and i need to create a user control like the following image:

Which has a vertical slider, a range of numbers and a graph that represent the selected value over the total being able the user to increment and decrease the value with the slider.

The problem is that i don't know how to create such a slider and i am also having some problems to draw the colour bar filled.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is what i have in xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tenaris.SM.View.CCMOperativeScreen.View.Controls.SetPointSteelLevel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid>
         <Slider Orientation="Vertical"></Slider>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource GridValueCell}" Text="88" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource GridValueCell}" Text="87" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource GridValueCell}" Text="86" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SetPointPresetNumber}" Text="85" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SetPointPresetNumber}" Text="84" Grid.Row="4"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SetPointPresetNumber}" Text="83" Grid.Row="5"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SetPointPresetNumber}" Text="82" Grid.Row="6"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource GridValueCell}" Text="81" Grid.Row="7"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource GridValueCell}" Text="80" Grid.Row="8"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource GridValueCell}" Text="79" Grid.Row="9"/>

    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
        <Rectangle>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#303030" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset=".5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#303030" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You need to show some effort. Post the code/XAML of what you already tried. Otherwise this question will get closed as too broad.

Comment: As HighCore has said, you need to show us what you already have. IMO if i was doing something like this i would do a composite of a range slider and a progress bar whose value is bound to the range scale of the slider. See this link perhaps for customising a progress bar [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167867/progress-bar-with-dynamic-text-text-color-update)

Answer (score -1):

Dude, you need to learn how to search for help. If you type *Slider class* into a search engine, the very first result will almost certainly be for the API page on MSDN: [`Slider` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The vast majority of these API pages on MSDN have detailed descriptions and often code examples to help you... *use them*. If you had looked there, you'd have seen that you don't have to manually add the numbers to the side of the `Slider`... they will be added by the control *if you set the right settings on the control*.

Next: [`Rectangle` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). On this page, you'll find a `Height` property that *Gets or sets the suggested height of the element*. We can use that to change the `Height` of the rectangle/bar. You could do that in two ways... either by manually setting `Rectangle.Height = newValue`, or by using [data `Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)... again, MSDN to the rescue.

Finally to the `Style`... your bar looks like it has one grey `Rectangle` in the background that doesn't move and then one on top of it (with a small `Margin` set on it). You could put both of these into the same `grid` cell making sure to declare the back one first. I hope that helps.

Good luck with your interesting project.

Comment: Please do not be abusive with your answers.  If you think the question is not worth answering, then don't answer.  Otherwise, simply add the MSDN links and move on.

Comment: @Jim, thank you for your comment. Perhaps you could highlight the part of my answer that is abusive? I answered the question. I provided helpful tips on how the question author could find solutions by themselves in future and I even wished them good luck. I'm struggling to find any abuse in my answer at all.

Comment: "Dude, you need to learn how to search for help. " is unnecessary.  People often start at stack overflow for help because the community keeps it kind.